# First submit of Ajax Form works, but second submit does nothing

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit

I want to add and remove localized names for a country-object via ajax. Therefore i have build two partial views. The first one contains the generel edit funcionality for the country-object and the second partial view (which will be rendered inside the first one) contains the logic to add/remove localized names.

1st partial view:

```
@model CountryViewModel

// scripts here

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
    [...] // the fields of the object to edit...
    </fieldset>
}

// this tag will be updated by the partial view
<div id="localizedNamesOverview"> 

@Html.Partial( "LocalizedNamesOverview",
               Model.LocalizedNames,
              new ViewDataDictionary 
              { 
                 { "countryId", Model.CountryId } 
              } )

</div>
```

2nd partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<LocalizedNameViewModel>

<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td> @item.Language </td>
        <td> @item.Name </td>
        <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink( "Delete",
                              "DeleteLocalizedName",
                              "Country",
                              new { countryId = this.ViewData[ "countryId" ], 
                                    localizedNameId = item.CountryI18nId },
                              new AjaxOptions
                              {
                                 UpdateTargetId="localizedNamesOverview",
                                 InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
                                 HttpMethod="POST"
                              } )
        </td>
    </tr>
}

@using( Ajax.BeginForm( "AddLocalizedName",
                        "Country",
                        new { countryId = this.ViewData[ "countryId" ] },
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                           UpdateTargetId = "localizedNamesOverview",
                           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                           HttpMethod = "POST"
                        } ) )
{
   <tr>
      <td> <input class="text-box single-line" id="LanguageId" name="LanguageId" value="" type="text" /> </td>
      <td> <input class="text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" value="" type="text" /> </td>
      <td> <input type="submit" value="Add new localized name" /> </td>
   </tr>
}

</table>
```

The dedicated controller returns the 2nd partial view when a localized name is either added or removed and replaces itself by adding the content into the 'localizedNamesOverview' from the 1st view. So far this works as i expected.

The problem now is this behaviour works just one time. If i have added or removed a name successfully i cannot delete/add a second one. At the moment i can't see where the problem is, because the generated html looks equals after the first submission.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i figured out what the problem was:

When the first request is made and the 2nd partial view is re-rendered it loses the ViewData information (`countryId`) from the parent which is needed to generate the working links (delete-link for each existing localized-name).

The same problem applies to the sourrounding ajax-form which also loses the id. Through some repositioning of the code i could fix the problem. I placed the `@using( Ajax.BeginForm...` code from the 2nd partial view to the parent view so it will not be regenerated after the ajax-request.

1st partial view (updated):

```
@using( Ajax.BeginForm( "AddLocalizedName",
                        "Country",
                        new { countryId = this.ViewData[ "countryId" ] },
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                          UpdateTargetId = "localizedNamesOverview",
                          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                          HttpMethod = "POST"
                        } ) )
{

// this tag will be updated by the partial view
<div id="localizedNamesOverview"> 

@Html.Partial( "LocalizedNamesOverview",
               Model.LocalizedNames,
               new ViewDataDictionary 
               { 
                  { "countryId", Model.CountryId } 
               } )

</div>

}
```

The delete-link problem could be solved because my model `LocalizedNameViewModel` also contains the dedicated `countryId` and so i take it from there.

2nd partial view (updated):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink( "Delete",
                  "DeleteLocalizedName",
                  "Country",
                  new { countryId = item.CountryId, // took countryId from the model
                        localizedNameId = item.CountryI18nId },
                  new AjaxOptions
                      {
                        UpdateTargetId="localizedNamesOverview",
                        InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod="POST"
                      } )
```